# Matplotlib getting z data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im new to working with matplotlib on python. Im trying to extract the x,y,z from a contour on python. I can get the x,y but for whatever reason, not the z.

The code im working with was an example i found on Stackoverflow

```
import numpy as np
import mpldatacursor
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x_list = np.array([-1,2,10,3])
y_list = np.array([3,-3,4,7])
z_list = np.array([5,1,2.5,4.5])
fig, ax= plt.subplots()

def gety(x,y):
    s = ax.format_coord(x,y)
    out = ""
    for i in range(s.find('y')+2,s.find('z')-2):
        out = out+s[i]
    return float(out)

def getxyz(event):
    s = ax.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    print(s)



plt.connect('button_press_event', gety)



fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', getxyz)

N = int(len(z_list)**.5)
z = z_list.reshape(N, N)
plt.imshow(z, extent=(np.amin(x_list), np.amax(x_list), np.amin(y_list), np.amax(y_list)), norm=LogNorm(), aspect = 'auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

whenever i click i get an x and y.

Ive tried stackoverflow.com/a/9673338/1002176 this solution and this is what it spits out

```
def gety(x,y):
    s = ax.format_coord(x,y)
    out = ""
    for i in range(s.find('y')+2,s.find('z')-2):
        out = out+s[i]
    return float(out)
```

The traceback is this

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 270, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\Downloads\array.py", line 12, in gety
    s = ax.format_coord(x,y)
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

im not sure where im going wrong...any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Share the whole code and whole traceback. I can't see where you are making a call to gety().

Comment: You are calling gety with one argument instead of two.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I updated it, i found more success from using (event). All it tells me is that im missing y

Comment: @Tarik Im not sure how im only calling one arguement, im just triggering the with an event?

Comment: Accept the edits. And when writing code use triple ticks -> ```  your_code ```

Comment: i accepted an edit about the tags, and fixed the traceback to be as code. Any idea on why its not showing the z data? I know event.zdata doesnt exist, but i can see the z data when i plot the graph on the bottom right corner, i just cant seem to extract it

Comment: As per documentation, "Connect event with string s to func. The signature of func is:
`def func(event)`" Accordingly gety should be defined with a single argument.